# How do I know which ssh key is used in my github account?

Tags: github, ssh

When I go to the [SSH keys page in my GitHub account](https://github.com/settings/keys), I see a key whose identity starts with "c5:42:08:9d:39:22..."

On my computer, in the ".ssh" folder, I have several files that look like public SSH keys, but none of them contains a string similar to the above. For example, one 
of the files "id_rsa.pub" contains a string that starts with "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABA..." there are other similar files that probably represent different keys.

How can I identify which of the files, if any, represents the actual key that is in my github account?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

"`c5:42:08:9d:39:22...`" isn't the key, but rather the key's [fingerprint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_fingerprint). You can see your key's fingerprint using [`ssh-keygen`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen):

```
ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Where

- `-l` means we want to see the key's fingerprint
- `-f ~/.ssh/id_rsa` is a path to the key whose fingerprint we want to see

On older versions of OpenSSH, you may need to also specify that you want the SHA256 fingerprint rather than another hash like MD5, since SHA256 is what GitHub shows in its web interface:

```
ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_rsa -E sha256
```

You should get the same fingerprint from the public part as from the private part of the keypair.

Comment: As of at least October 2021, GitHub now shows the SHA256 fingerprint, so use: `ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: @Kyle, well, it depends what your local OpenSSH's default is. With an older OpenSSH you might still need to provide the `-E`, just with a different argument: `-E sha256`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: On even older versions of OpenSSH that don't have the -E argument, you can generate the fingerprint manually: `awk '{print $2}' <path-to-public-key> | base64 -d | sha256sum -b | sed 's/ .*$//' | xxd -r -p | base64`